Has my website been hacked?
On four of my websites, the complete public_html folder was wiped clean.  They are all on the same host.  I have one more on the same host and that was intact.

Curiously, it's only the public_html folder that was wiped.  Everything else such as backup scripts, cronjobs, certificates are all intact.

The host uses cpanel, and I note that the email servers, php version, and cpanel versions are new.  They have changed recently.

I have looked at the logs, but I cant see anything.  Maybe I don't know what to look for.

They send me emails on every login (supposedly from unknown ip addresses).  But they complain about connecting from my fixed ipaddress every time, so I have to ignore this valuable feature.


It seems to me that if this was a hack job, where my password had been compromised for SSH or FTP, then they would have deleted more files.
I am suspecting that my host has deleted everything and is keeping mum.
There must be some signs of hacking.  What can I do to determine if they were hacked?

I did find two compressed php files with random names on one of the sites - which I deleted.
cronjobs are intact.  On a friends site they had put a cronjob to replace standard php files with infected ones.


I expect it depends on the level of access you have to your sites.  Maybe there is something in the log files if you have that level of access.
Its possible but most likely you have not been hacked - why would a hacker do this - it does not lead to an outcome of value for them.
Speculating wildly I do wonder if your provider lost data, or if they are using block devices and sharding, and they are having issues with the shards.  Its a double-edged sword, but if you have your own VM rebooting might bring your data back [ but its unlikely ].  of-course, if there are traces of hacking, some of these may be wiped when you reboot. - and this all assumes thats even an option.
Update
Your update implies you have been hacked . php files with random names are common for hacking - they often contain code to get a shell/execute arbitrary code/use a control server for the same.    If you have access to the PHP config and don't need to execute shell scripts adding/editing your php.ini file to add
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_get_handler,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_async_signals,pcntl_unshare,

Will do a lot to mitigate the exploitation of shells - although if people can write a php file to your system you have problems anyway as you can still do quite a lot with just PHP.
Something else - if your system is hacked, after removing the hacked files you may want to reboot this system (its crude - if you have shell access and knowledge you can just try restart all the servers).  I've seen hacking php scripts survive reloading the webserver by staying in memory (and relaunching when they are about to expire I think) and continuously checking and rewriting a script file when its deleted to keep access - No cron required.

I suspect it's the host.  I am going to finally name them.  Crazy Domains from Australia.  The certificates stop working 3 to 4 times a year and they have to be reinstalled.  And they take forever to fix things.  If I hadn't paid for 10 years in advance, I would switch.

Restoring wasn't a problem as I keep a mirror image of all the sites on my PC.  And the databases are backed up nightly and archived.

@RohitGupta Based on my experiences with them, I'd concur its way more likely to be the CD then a hacker.

Ditto to @davidgo, I wouldn't trust crazy domains with a domain registration.

At first glance, all the files (under public_html) had been deleted on 4 of my sites.  On one of them I found two random named PHP files. Thinking it was an artefact, I deleted them.  I keep mirror images of all my sites, so it was easy to replace everything and all sprung to life.
When I added another page and went to the Google Search Console, I noted that there had been 3000+ sitemap entries, all involving the two PHP files using params to make the urls.
https://example.com/product/acafardq1476537?id=428
I don't have a a file or folder of the name product.
An answer to the question is - Check Google Search Console for unusual events.

OMG NO. Google is NOT the place to go to find out if your site has been hacked. Leaving aside the preventative measures, and how you do recovery (which you still need to do) then a HIDS is the best way to monitor integrity of a small scale deployment.

You have also probably destroyed critical evidence you need to ientify what was EXPLOITED to deploy these scripts. Expect similar or worse to reappear.
